# How to move the focus to another element using the tab key

Tags: c#, html, css

I faced a problem. I have a modal window with close, cancel and submit buttons. For example, when I click on the close button and try to use the tab key to get the next element, the focus immediately switches to the footer, but not the next element. I need to make the focus after pressing the close, submit or cancel button go to the next item (Open Calculator)

Code for modal

```
<div id="special-needs-consent-form" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg animated zoomIn animated-3x" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" aria-label="@SpecialNeeds.ConsentForm">
                <h3 class="modal-title">@SpecialNeeds.ConsentForm</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="@Buttons.Close" onclick="removeCheckedSpecialNeeds()"><span aria-hidden="true"><em class="zmdi zmdi-close"></em></span></button>
            </div>
    
            <div class="modal-body">
<div>
```

```
    <div class="modal-footer" aria-label="@Everything.ConsentFooter">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="removeCheckedSpecialNeeds()">@Buttons.Cancel</button>
        <button id="consent-submit-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-raised">@Buttons.Submit</button>
    </div>
```

code for The element to focus on after clicking the close submit or cancel button

```
<div class="radio-primary col-lg-12">
             @if (RBBConfiguration.CurrentConfig.EnableFeeSubsidyExternalUrl)
              {
                  <a class="button" target="_blank" href="@(Model.FeeSubsidyExternalLink)" tabindex="0">@Model.FeeSubsidyExternalLinkText</a>
              }
              else
              {
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".subsidy-calculator:not(.show)" id="feeCalculator" class=" ml-4" tabindex="0">@Everything.OpenFeeCalculator</a>
              }
</div>
```

I tried to use tabindex = (1, 2, 3 etc.) elements, but it is not working correctly

Comment: Here is a how modal window starts <div id="special-needs-consent-form" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg animated zoomIn animated-3x" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" aria-label="@SpecialNeeds.ConsentForm">
     <h3 class="modal-title">@SpecialNeeds.ConsentForm</h3>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="@Buttons.Close" onclick="removeCheckedSpecialNeeds()"><span aria-hidden="true"><em class="zmdi zmdi-close"></em></span></button>
    </div>

Comment: Put any additional code in your question post not in comments, for readability purpose. And JavaScript and C# are not the same programming languages.

Comment: @Aleksandar I added the code but it didn't fit all that's why I decided to add it in a comment, I'll fix it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a simple onkeydown method:

```js
let counter = 0;
document.body.onkeydown = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault()
  if (ev.key == "Tab") {
    if (counter % 2 == 0) {
      //focus on input
      document.querySelector("#key").focus();
      document.querySelector("p").style.color = "";
    } else {
      //"focus" on paragraph
      document.querySelector("#key").blur();
      document.querySelector("p").style.color = "red";
    }
    counter++;
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="key">
<p>hello</p>
```

click on the window and click on the tab

I recommend to study this table:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZXWl.png)